# Evaluation of limit using $1$ st principle

Tags: limits

> Express the following limits as $f'(c)$ for some function $f$ and some number $c$
>
> $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{5(1+h)^{20}-6(1+h)^3+1}{h}$$

What i try

I have tried using D L Hopital rule

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{100(1+h)^{19}-18(1+h)^2}{1}=82$$

But i did not understand How can i express in the form of $f'(c)$

Seems that to solve it using $1$ st principle.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put $f(x)=5x^{20}-6x^3$. Then $f(1)=-1$ and so$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{5(1+h)^{20}-6(1+h)^3+1}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h+1)-f(1)}h=f'(1).$$